# Template helper inside template instantiation

Tags: html, meteor, meteor-helper

Is it possible to call a template helper inside a template instantiation?

For my project, I have created templates for all my custom-styled input elements to make them re-usable. For example, the checkbox would look like:

```
<template name="myCheckbox">
   <input type="checkbox" id="{{id}}" class="myCheckbox ..." />
</template>
```

To use it, I simply go:

```
{{> myCheckbox id="allowEdit"}}
```

This makes it easy for me to control the look and feel of my inputs across the entire project, as I only need to change the template in order to update all my checkboxes. This works fine, but now I need a template helper to add a "checked" attribute to my checkbox based on the DB. E.g.

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    checkAllowEdit: function() {
        return (this.allowEdit) ? "checked" : "";
    }
});

{{> myCheckbox id="allowEdit" {{checkAllowEdit}} }}
```

This doesn't work. Meteor doesn't like me trying to use a helper inside the instantiation. So my question is:
**Is there any way to call a template helper inside a template instantiation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking a checkbox from a helper, you can use [this Blaze feature](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#conditional-attributes-with-no-value-eg-checked-selected): have your helper return a boolean and just assign it to your child template's checkbox `checked` property.

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    checkAllowEdit: function() {
        return Boolean(this.allowEdit); // Boolean cast may be unnecessary
    }
});

<template name="myTemplate">
  {{!-- things... --}}
  {{> myCheckbox id="allowEdit" checked=checkAllowEdit }}
</template

<template name="myCheckbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{id}}" class="myCheckbox ..." checked={{checked}} />
</template>
```

A more natural way would be to use a helper in the `myCheckbox` template instead of the `myTemplate` one:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{!-- things... --}}
  {{> myCheckbox id="allowEdit" }}
</template>

Template.myCheckbox.helpers({
    checkAllowEdit: function() {
        return Boolean(this.allowEdit); // Boolean cast may be unnecessary
    }
});

<template name="myCheckbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{id}}" class="myCheckbox ..." checked={{checkAllowEdit}} />
</template>
```

But I have a feeling you want it in `myTemplate` on purpose.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!